# How to count number of times word is repeated in C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

Hi I am having some trouble with this code.

Comment: why not simply use `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` to map word to its frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubble sort:

```
vector<string> strings = split(str);
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < strings.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (strings[j + 1] < strings[j]) {
            string tmp = strings[j];
            strings[j] = strings[j + 1];
            strings[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
   }
}
```

Counting words after ordering:

```
string prev = strings[0];
int counter = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    if (strings[i] == prev) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        cout << prev << ": " << counter << " ";
        prev = strings[i];
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I do a counter at the end to add it to the vector<string> strings?

Comment: to add what? strings in the vector are just swapped

Comment: too keep track of the number of times each word is repeated. Example out put: "This is is a test" this: 1 is: 2 a: 1 test: 1

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error for "unexpected type name" is there some library in addition to <vector> and <string> I need to import?

Comment: No, i don't have any libraries in addition to iostream, vector and string

Answer (score 5):

The best way to count unique words is to use `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` and then increment values in the map: `wordMap[word]++;` Note that if this is the first occurrence of the word, default value would be created and it is 0, which suits the task well.

Beside this, it is not good to implement sorting yourself when there is std::sort which is quite good for great majority of cases.

Comment: Sorry I can only use bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::find from `algorithm`:

```
std::find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), the_word_you_looking_for) != strings.end()
```

This returns a **bool (true if present, false otherwise)**.

You can also set a counter and then increment it on every `true` encountered.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately i can't use anything besides bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing the same will be to keep all the sub-string into vectors and then use std::count function on the vector and put the results into a map. Here is the sample code

```
std::string s = "This is very good text and is really good to read";
        // Putting all substrings into a vector.. Need code to do that, for simplicity I am showing here manually
        vector<string> v1;
        v1.push_back("This");
        v1.push_back("is");
        v1.push_back("very");
        v1.push_back("good");
        v1.push_back("text");
        v1.push_back("and");
        v1.push_back("is");
        v1.push_back("rally");
        v1.push_back("good");
        v1.push_back("to");
        v1.push_back("read");
        // Map to create the result
        map<string, int> mp;
        for (auto v : v1) {
            size_t n = std::count(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v);
            mp[v] = n;
        }

        for (auto mvalue : mp) {
            cout << "String = " << mvalue.first.c_str() << "  Count Is " << mvalue.second << endl;
        }
```